# Multiple reverse proxy servers to a single backend server

Tags: networking, proxy, load-balancing, reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy

I'm relatively new to networking and currently working on a project where I need to set up multiple reverse proxy servers that distribute incoming traffic to a single backend server. The goal is to achieve equal distribution of the traffic across the proxy servers, with each server handling approximately 50% of the requests. (2 reverse proxy servers in this case)

I have been researching various proxy server technologies and load balancing techniques, but I'm unsure about the best approach to accomplish this setup.

So far, I have considered **frp and Caddy** as potential solutions. However, I've encountered some challenges. Frp seems to support only one proxy server with multiple backend servers, and I'm looking for the opposite setup. I want to create multiple reverse proxy servers directing traffic to a single backend server.

I specifically want to implement reverse proxy on TCP transmission. I have been struggling to find suitable solutions for the past few days.

An example of the reverse proxy setup I'm aiming for is a domain like **a1.fastapi03.online**. If you check on dnschecker.org, you can see they have multiple IP addresses for their reverse proxy load balancing.

I want to achieve the same thing but have been unsuccessful so far.

Thank you for taking the time to read this and considering offering help! ❤️

[image]